# Having Separate Update actions for different params in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**(post updated down below)**

**My issue:** Is that I need a separate update action for the different params in my controller. I need a general update actions for params (minus params in the separate update actions/methods), an update action for :video, and an update action for :order_status

**Question:** How can I efficiently accomplish having multiple update actions in my controller?

Here is an idea of what I want, and it doesn't work:

```
  def charge_update
    respond_to do |format|
      @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
      @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
      if @order.update(order_charge)
        if user_signed_in? && user.seller?
                      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                        :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
                        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                        :currency    => 'usd',
                        :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                        :destination => {
                          :amount => @amount_seller ,
                          :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                        }
                      })
          @order.order_status = "charged"
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def cancel_update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.cancel_update(order_update)
        if user_signed_in?
          if @order.order_status = "cancelled"

            format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully cancelled.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update( order_params.except(:order_status) )
        if user_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
        if buyer_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

private

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :image,:description)
    end

    def order_status
      params.require(:order).permit(:order_status)
    end

    def order_charge
      params.require(:order).permit(:video)
    end
...
```

My issues with what I need to accomplish:

I want a separate action for when an order_status is changed, for each value. Most importantly, I want a certain message to be displayed depending on the value that the order_status column is changed to.

Most important issue:

I need a separate update action for charging customers. This is most important because i can't just have a customer being charged when someone updates a name, or when a seller updates an order_status, etc.

I'm doing something wrong or i need to set up the routes to have the ability to allow multiple update actions?

So how i can separate the updates and params?

***UPDATE***

I embedded the update methods into the one original method like so...

but i have one issue now, the message notices don't appear correct to the update param. The "Order was successfully updated" appears, which isn't the customized one for when i upload a video or change the ordeR_status column

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if params["order_status"]
        if user_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully order_status.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
        if params["video"]
          @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
          @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
          if @order.update(order_charge)
            if user_signed_in? && user.seller?
                          charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                            :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
                            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                            :currency    => 'usd',
                            :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                            :destination => {
                              :amount => @amount_seller ,
                              :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                            }
                          })
              @order.order_status = "charged"
              format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end
        if @order.update(order_params)
          if user_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
          if buyer_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

**So I have two issues now:**

1. The customized messages don't show
2. and under the :video param update, I want the order status to change the "charged", but what i currently have doesn't do it

Anyone have any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: you may look in an other direction. there is a way too find out what fields has been changed in rails. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: thanks.  that helps for changing the order_status, but not sure how it helps for executing the charge.  ive been told by a more experienced coder than myself i should be creating a controller for each action to accomlish what i want because the way i solved it (down below in the response to my own post) is too "brute".. it works but im going to look into creating a controller for charging and changing the order_status ... and i assume ill be combining them with a join table but ill see.... if you have any insight on this, feel free to let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved it so far.  :::

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_status)
        if user_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully order_status.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
        if @order.update(order_charge)
          @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
          @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
          if @order.update(order_charge)
            if current_user.seller?
                          charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                            :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
                            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                            :currency    => 'usd',
                            :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                            :destination => {
                              :amount => @amount_seller ,
                              :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                            }
                          })
              @order.order_status = "charged"
              format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end
        if @order.update(order_params)
          if user_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
          if buyer_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end

private

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :image, :video, :description)
    end

    def order_status
      params.require(:order).permit(:order_status)
    end

    def order_charge
      params.require(:order).permit(:video)
    end
end
```

If anyone sees this and thinks they have a better way, please let me know.  I'm not sure how convenient or efficient this may be, (embedding all into one method, etc.)  but it seems to work.  My only issue is that

1. When i change order_status to cancel, no message appears but it works.
2. when i change fill in the video param, the order_status message appears.  Which i understand but i don't understand why it won't appear when i change the status to cancel - and btw, cancel is a enum of "2".

Comment: This isn't going to be an accepted response.  I have been told to explore creating a separate controller for each separate update action.  If anyone has some insight, feel free to comment or respond to the question!

Comment: Update.  I created a new controller for uploading files.  This way i can efficiently handle the uploading and then allow updating on it without worry of charging someone twice. The create action also looks for a previously updloaded file which will block the charge - this is just an added layer of protection aside from the views